# Random HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway in PHP REST API

Tags: php, apache, fpm, bad-gateway, http-status-code-502

I have written a REST API in PHP using slim micro framework.

Hosted on Apache (Event MPM) + PHP8.0-FPM on 2-vCPU and 4 GiB RAM and 10Gbps N/w bandwidth behind LoadBalancer.

**Issue:**

The test program is receiving random *HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway* in response error. The frequency of the error is 10 out of 1500-2000 requests.

**Apache2.conf**

```
Timeout 600
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

**Apache Event MPM config:**

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    ServerLimit     50
    StartServers             25
    MinSpareThreads      75
    MaxSpareThreads      250
    ThreadLimit          256
    ThreadsPerChild      64
    MaxRequestWorkers     3200
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

**PHP-FPM config:**

```
pm.max_children=700
pm.start_servers=200
pm.min_spare_server=200
pm.max_spare_server=500
```

I have written a separate program in C# to stress test the REST API.

**Findings:**

- The server is running on 30-40% CPU and 700-900MB of RAM usage.
- I have checked apache access logs, and no Error 502 request log is
  there.
- I have checked apache error logs, and nothing is there as
  well.

What could be the issue? I do not know which area to debug forward.

Comment: Maybe check the LB logs?

Comment: @ChrisHaas. I have not configured LB for logs. May be i'll configure in some days.

Comment: The LB might be the one giving you the 502